# aggregation in a DAO implantation in Java

Tags: java, dao

I want to implement DAO in a Java program.  I know that the aggregation is stronger than composition; My question is how can we see this difference in Project.java for example because a project aggregate many requirement (while a milestone consists of many requirements)?

Comment: There are so many problems with this it's hard to know where to start. Your listRequirement should be of type `List', not 'ArrayList' and should be called `requirements`. `DAO` should be `Dao`. `Implementation` should be `impl`. Your DAO shouldn't have setters and adders, they should be on the Milestone itself. The DAO should only have CRUD methods -- create, read (finders), update, and delete. You use the term DAO, but you don't have one nor do you talk about one. You have no way of navigating from project to milestones. Etc. I think you need to start again think this through.

Answer (score 0):

The semantic difference between the two cannot be seen at this level.

It could be seen at the DAO or even DB schema *implementation* level, where the entities that have a composition relationship with its container should be deleted when the container object ceases to exist.